# How do I get a user's phone number or other contact details from a Lync contact card?

Tags: wpf, lync

How do I get a user's phone number or other contact details from a Lync contact card, in my Lync WPF application? (By user I mean Incoming Caller or the Logged in User)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user presence with a `contactCard` XML property (of the type `PresenceCategoryWithMetaData`), you can parse it using `new ContactCard(categoryWithMetaData);`.

The resulting object will have a property `public Collection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; }`, amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually mean (or need to use) the contact card?

If you have the Contact object (which you can easily get of either the logged in sure or of any incoming call user) the you could use [Contact.GetContactInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh380108%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to get your information that way.

Comment: I believe there is information in a ContactCard that is not available using GetContactInformation.